# Compare two datagridview and remove rows dependent on row properties

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, rows

I am currently working in vb.net windows form applications. I have two `DataGridViews` and I want to cross reference the rows and remove certain rows out of `datagridview1`, depending on if a `checkbox` is checked in `datagridview2`. This problem arises when I check a box for an action taken by a front end user in `datagridview1` that updates `datagridview2`. But, when I refresh both `DataGridViews`, `datagridview2` shows that this action has been taken, but the `checkbox` column in `datagridview1` goes back to unchecked, thus telling the front end user to repeat this action.

On a side note all the data is bound to an sql table, except the `checkbox` column in `datagridview1`. Also note, I have a refresh button that repeats the load event to refresh both tables.

*Page Load Event Handler:*

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'load datagridview1'
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim AA As New DataSet
    connectionstring = "Data source = .\sqlexpress; integrated security = true"
    connection = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
    sql = "SELECT Shear FROM production.dbo.stagingcompleted"
    Try
        connection.Open()
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionstring)
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        connection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    'load datagridview2'
    connectionstring = "Data source = .\sqlexpress; integrated security = true"
    connection = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
    sql = "SELECT * FROM production.dbo.tblFCOrdered"
    Try
        connection.Open()
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionstring)
        adapter.Fill(AA)
        connection.Close()
        DataGridView2.DataSource = AA.Tables(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

*DataGridView1 Event Handler (CellContentClick):*

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    'update datagridview1 to the action for that row complete'
    If e.ColumnIndex <> 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim v As String = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value
    Select Case MsgBox("Are you sure shear " & v & " has been cut?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        Case MsgBoxResult.No
            Exit Sub
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            Try
                Dim connstring = "Data Source=.\sqlexpress; integrated security = true"
                Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
                    conn1.Open()
                    Using comm1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Production.dbo.tblFCOrdered SET FormChannel = 1 WHERE SHEAR = '" & v & "'", conn1)
                        comm1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        conn1.Close()
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
    End Select
```

Comment: yup, just downvote it, typical.

Answer (score 0):

I am possibly incorrect and I apologise if you have already tried this. I believe you might benefit from reading up about the page life-cycle, order event handlers and the effects of `PostBack` (for example [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/y3bwdsh3(v=vs.80).aspx))

> In server controls, certain events, typically click events, cause the page to be posted back immediately to the server. Change events in HTML server controls and Web server controls, such as the TextBox control, do not immediately cause a post. Instead, they are raised the next time a post occurs.

In regards to `PostBack` and `Page.Load`:

> After a page has been posted back, the page's initialization events (`Page_Init` and `Page_Load`) are raised, and then control events are processed. You should not create application logic that relies on the change events being raised in a specific order unless you have detailed knowledge of page event processing.

I think that part of the problem you are experiencing is that the first thing the page will do when you trigger a `PostBack`, e.g. by clicking on a cell, is the code which you have in your `Page.Load` event handler. In your code you will find that when the page is processed (on `PostBack`) the first thing that happens is that the grids are data bound. Because of this any changes made will not be persisted when the other event handlers are called. A common check before performing actions such as data binding in the `Page.Load` function is to check that the page is not being posted back, if `IsPostBack = true` it is likely that you will want to skip such actions.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I am refreshing the datagridview and it is causing datagridview1 to refresh and show the row the front end user has already taken care of. If I could, i would just DELETE that row but unfortunately other places in the facility are using this table which makes it impossible to just delete the row. What I need is a loop within a loop to check and make sure that datagridview1 will not reload the already completed task. Its something like this pretty much, IF SHEAR in DGV2 is checked as complete THEN the corresponding shear in DGV should not be selected.